# How to select multiple date in calendar view in android

Tags: android

I want to select multiple dates in calendar view. Some dates highlight yellow or some red etc. I want same as below image:-

[image]

Comment: http://www.toptal.com/android/android-customization-how-to-build-a-ui-component-that-does-what-you-want

Comment: @Annajain what code have you try so far?

Comment: Verify here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25116897/i-want-to-select-multiple-dates-in-calendar-in-android