# how to implement Android material calendar day view customization and implement swipe to choose functionality

Tags: android, calendar

Need full functionality calendar like FScalendar in IOS, need to add rates with every date and need multi-select on dates

[Swipe select like this][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQJWa.gif

Comment: just do google for your homework task !

Comment: Sorry, it's not a homework task and I did try all the example given on calendar, nothing match to IOS FScalendar.

Comment: You Have To Customise That Library Code As Per Your Requirements ,As Per My Knowledge There Is Not Any Exact Code Which Match Your FScalendar Functions.

Comment: there is no problem in customization in IOS, but I need same that functionality in Android.

Comment: Yes Thats Why You Have To Modify One Of The Bestfit Lib From github or google because exact match library for android i think not available

Answer (score 0):

follow this link to choosing multiple date it can help you

- [git hub](https://github.com/square/android-times-square)
- [multi-datepicker-calendar](http://codesfor.in/android-multi-datepicker-calendar-example/)
- [stack-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25116897/i-want-to-select-multiple-dates-in-calendar-in-android)